Minimize UWP programmatically on Windows 11
I am looking for the C# way to minimize UWP app on Windows 11.
Currently I am using following approach that still works on Wn10 but stopped to work on Win11.
Minimize UWP programmatically
Please assist to find a way to minimize UWP app to taskbar in Windows 11.

Define "stopped to work"? Can you still use that API? What infos and resourceInfos contain?
